# Regex to extract numeric string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Hi I don't feel very well with regular expressions.
What I would like to achieve is to extract a numeric substring (only 0-9 digits) from the input string.

- The numeric string that is searched should be preceded only by a
  semicolon (`;`), space ( ) or should be placed exactly at the begining
  of the input (not line).
- The numeric string that is searched should be followed only by a semicolon (`;`), the end of line or the end of the  input string.

Exemplary input:

`;x; ;SrvId=3993;ad257c823; 435223;`

Output:

`435223`

I tried: `[ \A|;|[ ]]\d*[\r|;|\Z]` but it did not worked, it did not even compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
string resultString = null;
try {
    resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"(?<=\A|\s+|;)(\d+)(?=$|;|\Z)").Groups[1].Value;
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Break down :

(?<=\A|\s+|;)

Posiive lookbehind : start of input or at least one whitespace character or a semicolon.

(\d+) at least one digit

(?=$|;|\Z)

Positive lookahead either end of line, or semicolon or and of input.

Input : `;x; ;SrvId=3993;ad257c823; 435223;`

Output of group 1 : `435223`

Comment: @HasanKhan Can you provide an input which makes it to match where it shouldn't match?

Comment: @FailedDev it doesn't match the number at the end of line when there is more text in new line

Comment: @HasanKhan I don't see any new line in OP examples. Do you?

Comment: @FailedDev "The numeric string that is searched should be followed only by a semicolon (;), the **end of line or the end of the input string**."

Comment: @HasanKhan You can write whatever bold letters you want, however this still doesn't change the fact that there is no new line in the OPs post :) Also if my english don't deceive me the end of line should be the last part of the string. OP doesn't mention possibility of multiple new lines. So you are wrong - again :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
^(?:[; ]?)(?:.*?)([0-9]+);$
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `^.*[ ;](\d+)[;\n]?$` will capture the numbers you're interested in although you may have to change the \n to \r\n depending on the line endings of your input file.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression should be this:

```
"[; ]{1}[0-9]+($|[^0-9]+)"
```

Comment: This returns 435223; which includes the semi-colon

Answer (score 0):

Try using this expression

```
(\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)
```